# how to represent null value in xml file which is exported from mysql

Tags: c#, xml

XML file looks like below when imported from Mysql:

```
 <data>
 <row>
 <id>1</id><name>ram</name><sno>(NULL)</sno>
 </row>
 <row>
 <id>2</id><name>ram</name><sno>(NULL)</sno>
 </row>
 </data>
```

I am reading xml file into dataset.

`if(ds.Tables[0].rows[0][sno] == DBNULL.Value)` condition is always false.

Where `sno` column values are taken as strings.
I want represent them into nulls and make condition true.

Answer (score 0):

```
<"Name of the Column" i:nil="true" />
```

This way you can represent null value in xml file. Now you can check that value is null or not by this.

Check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/runeetv/archive/2012/10/17/9416542.aspx)

Comment: it gives error as 'xsi' is an undeclared namespace when when i call readxml on dataset.

Comment: it gives error as 'xsi' is an undeclared namespace when when i call readxml on dataset. My xml file doesnot contain any extra tags to support " xsi " .Iam not sure of what tags to add into my .xml file to support xsi:nil="true" or i:nil="true"

Comment: <sno xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></sno> will do